# Enter some parameter to program with python

Tags: python, c, shell

If I have source code like this

```
#include <stdio.h> //test

int main(void)
{
    int tmp;
    scanf("%d", &tmp);
    printf("%d\n", tmp);
}
```

I know I can give parameter with python like `(python -c 'print "1234"';cat) | ./test`

But I have problem with other case. For example if program get integer with scanf and string with read.

```
#include <stdio.h>  //test
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
        int tmp1=0;
        char tmp2[100]={0};

        scanf("%d", &tmp1);
        read(0, tmp2, 100);

        printf("%d %s\n", tmp1, tmp2);
}
```

I tried like this `(python -c 'print "134\n"+"Hello World\n"';cat) | ./test` I think result may be `134 Hello World` However result was just `134`. I can't input string with this method.

I can't find other way to solve this problem. Is there any method to solve this problem?

I'm using **x64 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and compile option was `-o test -m32 test.c`

Comment: Instead of supplying `\n` in python, Can't you just supply args to `test` and append `\n` to those args inside `test`? `(python -c 'print "134"+"Hello World"';cat)`. The Python line does print `134 Hello World` but on separate lines. You must handle that in your `test`

Comment: I want to change my test program but I can't change that source code. Because I want to practice that kind of input. And `(python -c 'print "134"+"Hello World"';cat)` it doesn't work too.